# ¿Existe alguna palabra que signifique "perteneciente o relativo a los abuelos"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Hoy, jocosamente, he usado la expresión "ayuda abuelil" para indicar que necesitaba ayuda de los abuelos. Y ya me he quedado pensando en si realmente existe ese término. Usando el DIRAE he podido localizar los siguientes términos:

```
Adjetivo   Parentesco al que se refiere
---------------------------------------
Paterno    Padre
Materno    Madre
Parental   Padres
Filial     Hijos
Fraterno   Hermanos
Sororal    Hermana
```

El caso es que no encuentro ninguna palabra para el mismo adjetivo pero aplicado a los abuelos. He usado en la expresión inventada el sufijo *[-il](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KxNcOUu)* (forma adjetivos que suelen indicar relación o pertenencia), aunque lo mismo podría haber usado *[-ar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3NNxyGS)* (en los adjetivos significa condición o pertenencia) como en el resto de adjetivos similares.

La cuestión es: ¿existe, aunque no esté recogida por el DLE, alguna palabra que signifique "perteneciente o relativo a los abuelos" que se haya usado previamente en la literatura?

Comment: Lo de hermana no lo había oído jamás. Y ahora que lo sé supongo que llamar *sor* a las monjas tendrá algo que ver con esa raiz.

Comment: [Por aquí](http://www.foroderelojes.es/showthread.php/23919-PALABRAS-NECESARIAS-pero-que-NO-EST%C3%81N-en-el-DICCIONARIO) alguien dice que no: "No existen en el DRAE términos que puedan ser utilizados para expresar estos conceptos [en referencia a "ABUELIDAD/ABUELIL", que atribuye a Pedro Salinas Serrano en 1948]

Comment: @blonfu el origen es "soror", del latín "hermana carnal".

Comment: Ahora entiendo de donde sale lo de las _sorority & fraternity_ en las universidades de USA. _fraternity_ estaba fácil pero _sorority_ no me sonaba.

Comment: Según el buscador de [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=abuelerno), a varias personas ya se les ocurrió "abuelerno".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

| sustantivo | adjetivo |
| --- | --- |
| padres | parental |
| padre | paterno, paternal |
| madre | materno, maternal |
| hermanos | hermanal |
| hermano | fraterno |
| hermana | sororal |
| hijos | filial |
| sobrino | sobrinazgo `"Parentesco de sobrino."` `(nombre, no adjetivo)` |
| antepasados | [abolengo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=07ZgLnc) `(adjetivo desusado)` |

*Abolengo* se deriva de *abuelo* + *-engo*, pero no significa *"perteneciente o relativo a los abuelos"* específicamente desafortunadamente.

Además, existen estas palabras de raíces latinas en inglés (que no tienen cognados/análogos castellanos aceptados en la *RAE*):

| sustantivo | adjetivo |
| --- | --- |
| sobrino | nepotal |
| tío | avuncular |
| tía | materteral<sup>[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20130616211433/http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=19971119) [2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4W6JAgAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PR100&dq=materteral)</sup> `raro` |

Comment: Abolengo parece que fue pero su significado se desvió un poco. ¿Tal vez mejor que abuelil sea abuelezco.?

Comment: creo que el significado de abolengo hoy en dia sigue siendo correcto, 

la palabra no tiene que tener unicamente un solo significado, al igual que paternal, patriarcal o fraternal

Answer (score 5):

Dado que en latín "abuelo" era *avus*, lo "relativo al abuelo" debería ser ***ávico***. Pero por supuesto esta palabra no existe, aunque sí existe *atávico*, cuyo significado original habrá sido "relativo al tatarabuelo" y en español significa "arcaico".

Comment: "_atávico_ ... en español significa arcaico". Creo que no es exacto. En  http://dle.rae.es/?id=4BgZ7Qk se define **atávico** -> perteneciente o relativo a atavismo y en http://dle.rae.es/?id=4Bm02dM se define  **atavismo** como 1. m. Comportamiento que hace pervivir ideas o formas de vida propias de los antepasados.  2. m. Biol. Reaparición en los seres vivos de caracteres propios de sus ascendientes más o menos remotos. Mientras que http://dle.rae.es/?id=3RXoAXd  **arcaico** es: 1. adj. Muy antiguo o anticuado.  2. adj. Geol. Dicho de un período: Que es el más antiguo de la era precámbrica.